# Error create trigger

Tags: android, sql, triggers

I'm getting this error while trying to upgrade the database. I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper.

> 11-30 03:32:55.868: W/System.err(383): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "author_id": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TRIGGER
>   [update_increase_size]

Here is my script for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_increase_size]
AFTER INSERT
ON [quote]
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE author SET size = size+1 WHERE author_id = new.author_id;     
     UPDATE genre SET size = size+1 WHERE genre_id = new.genre_id;
END;
```

Can anyone spot me the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around with the problem. it seems that SQLiteAssetHelper is having trouble in updating script with trigger as trigger can have more than 1 semicolon. So what I did was to call the script manually using execSQL in onUpgrade method as follow:

```
private static final String TRIGGER_INCREASE_SIZE = "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS [update_increase_size] "
        + "AFTER INSERT "
        + "ON [quote] "
        + "FOR EACH ROW "
        + "BEGIN "
        + "UPDATE [author] SET size = size+1 WHERE [author_id] = new.[author_id]; "
        + "UPDATE [genre] SET size = size+1 WHERE [genre_id] = new.[genre_id]; "
        + "END;";

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVer, int newVer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(TRIGGER_INCREASE_SIZE);          
    super.onUpgrade(db, oldVer, newVer);
}
```

Hope this clear everything for whoever stumble upon similar problem in the future.